# Image appear when timer is at 1

Tags: swift

im making a reaction time app, and I have a label set to count with Seconds. I want to make my image appear when the label is at 1 second, but it doesn't appear. The timer works fine, just the image. Help me in swift please.

```
import UIKit

class timerViewController: UIViewController {

    var go = NSTimeInterval()
    var timer = NSTimer()


    @IBOutlet weak var tapStop: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var displayTimer: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if displayTimer.text == "00:01:00"{
            tapStop.image = UIImage(named: "carcrash")
        }


    }

    @IBAction func stop(sender: UIButton) {

        timer.invalidate()
    }


    @IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {

        if (!timer.valid) {
            let test:Selector = "updateTime"
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: test, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            go = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        }
    }

    func updateTime(){
        var timeNow = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        var pass: NSTimeInterval = timeNow - go


        let minutes1 = UInt8(pass / 60.0)
        pass -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes1) * 60)
        let seconds1 = UInt8(pass)
        pass -= NSTimeInterval(seconds1)
        let milli1 = UInt8(pass * 100)


        let minutes2 = String(format: "%02d", minutes1)
        let seconds2 = String(format: "%02d", seconds1)
        let milli2 = String(format: "%02d", milli1)
        displayTimer!.text = "\(minutes2):\(seconds2):\(milli2)"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put this:

```
if displayTimer.text == "00:01:00"{
    tapStop.image = UIImage(named: "carcrash")
}
```

in your `func updateTime()` instead of `viewDidLoad()`, and put them into main thread, so that your image will be updated on the UI. Your `func updateTime()` will look like this:

```
func updateTime(){
    var timeNow = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    var pass: NSTimeInterval = timeNow - go

    let minutes1 = UInt8(pass / 60.0)
    pass -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes1) * 60)
    let seconds1 = UInt8(pass)
    pass -= NSTimeInterval(seconds1)
    let milli1 = UInt8(pass * 100)


    let minutes2 = String(format: "%02d", minutes1)
    let seconds2 = String(format: "%02d", seconds1)
    let milli2 = String(format: "%02d", milli1)
    displayTimer!.text = "\(minutes2):\(seconds2):\(milli2)"

    if displayTimer.text == "00:01:00"{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            tapStop.image = UIImage(named: "carcrash")
        })    
    }

}
```